# Newbie: Ruby on rails. I am getting DoubleRenderError while using find_each

Tags: json, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have API method which return JSON data.
Example

```
 http://myapp/items/get_list_of_Item_IDs_from_some_where.json?days=50&location=CA
```

Method in the controller which is working:

```
def get_list_of_Item_IDs_from_some_where 
  item = Item.where("created_at >= ? and location = ?", Date.today - params[:days].to_i, params[:location])
    serialized_item_ids_and_updated_at = item.as_json(only: [:id, :updated_at])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { render json: serialized_item_ids_and_updated_at }
    end
end
```

Output:

```
[{"id":"12345","updated_at":"2016-11-18T20:31:23Z"},{"id":"12222","updated_at":"2016-11-18T20:39:18Z"}]
```

Method in the controller which is not working when I tired to use find_each in that method.

```
def get_list_of_Item_IDs_from_some_where 
  Item.where("created_at >= ? and location = ?", Date.today - params[:days].to_i, params[:location]).find_each do |item|
    serialized_item_ids_and_updated_at = item.as_json(only: [:id, :updated_at])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { render json: serialized_item_ids_and_updated_at }
    end
  end
end
```

Output:

I will get this error:

```
AbstractController::DoubleRenderError
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me.

```
def get_list_of_Item_IDs_from_some_where 
  serialized_item_ids_and_updated_at = []
  Item.where("created_at >= ? and location = ?", Date.today - params[:days].to_i, params[:location]).find_each do |item|
  serialized_item_ids_and_updated_at << item.as_json(only: [:id, :updated_at])
  end
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json { render json: serialized_item_ids_and_updated_at }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You are only allowed to render one time per request, when you execute looping with render in the block it will render as many as the total item in the collection.

here is solution from me:

```
def get_list_of_Item_IDs_from_some_where 
  jsons = Item.where("created_at >= ? and location = ?", Date.today - params[:days].to_i, params[:location]).to_json(only: [:id, :updated_at])
  render json: jsons
end
```

Comment: I want to used find_each in that method to process object in batches.

Comment: do you want stream the looping? what is your expectation json?

Comment: This is my expected JSON `[{"id":"12345","updated_at":"2016-11-18T20:31:23Z"},{"id":"12222","updated_at":"2016-11-18T20:39:18Z"}]`